# Deploy ML model in Databricks MLFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, databricks, mlflow

I have a ML model trained in dev environment and now I want to deploy this in PROD databricks which has different URL. I can download the dev model and then manually can be uploaded the pkl file to PROD DBFS. After downloading the model how can I deploy in prod MLFlow?

To download the model I have used following code

```
import os
import mlflow
from mlflow.store.artifact.models_artifact_repo import ModelsArtifactRepository
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("databricks")
model_name = "testingModel"
model_stage = "None" 
os.makedirs("model2", exist_ok=True)
local_path = ModelsArtifactRepository(f'models:/{model_name}/{model_stage}').download_artifacts("", dst_path='model2')
print(f'{model_stage} Model {model_name} is downloaded at {local_path}')
```